# Can't add { } to object in nodejs to mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to insert a document into a collection only if the parent's document exists, but I can't escape the {} from the object.

```
app.post("/addSkill", function(request, response){
    
    collection = db.collection("skills");

    var skill_category = request.body.skill_category;
    var skill_subcategory = request.body.skill_subcategory;
    var skill_name = request.body.skill_name;

    var firstData = {
        \{ \}, \{ skill_category \}
    };
    console.log("First data: " + firstData);
    var secondData = {
        \{ \}, \{ skill_category: \{ subcategory \}\}
    };
    console.log("Second data: " + secondData);


    if(collection.find(firstData)){
        console.log("Join to first data");
        if(collection.find(secondData)){
            console.log("Join to second data");
        }
        else{
            console.log("Not join to second data");
        }
    }
    else{
        console.log("Not join to first data");
    }
    return response.redirect('/');
});
```

The above code gives this error:

```
\{ \}, \{ skill_category \}
^
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

```
var firstData = {
    `{ }, { ${skill_category} }`
};
```

The above code gives this error:

```
`{ }, { ${skill_category} }`
^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected template string
```

Comment: What exactly were you expecting this to do?!

Comment: The goal is to add a document in the subcategory, and if it dosn't exist then it will create one in the category field. If the category dosn't exist then it will also create one with the subcategory and the document in it.

Comment: I mean what JavaScript object were you trying to construct? Right now the simple answer is that what you're writing is simply not valid JavaScript code, but it's not clear what you thought you would get.

Comment: The syntax to find in mongoDB is "db.skills.find({ }, { category: "subcategory" } )" so I attempt to send a object with that syntax to see if it returns true in case it exists

Comment: Right, but `{}, {webdev: {frontend: "angular"}}` is not _itself_ a valid value. And if you want to put things in an object you have to have _keys_ for the values. Maybe you want an array of values you can _spread_ to the function? Or maybe you don't need to assign to a value at all, just _call the function_ with the values you want.

Comment: The second parameter you pass to `.find()` is called `projection` and specifies the fields to return in the documents that match the query filter. Are you sure that's what you're intending to use?

Comment: I dont really know how to do it, but I know that I need to return true if the category or subcategory exists, but I can't know if the subcategory exists if I dont check first if the category exists. Here is the database:
db.skills {
 category: {
  subcategory: [skill_name, skill_name]
  subcategory: [skill_name, skill_name]
 }
 category: {
  subcategory: [skill_name, skill_name]
  subcategory: [skill_name, skill_name]
 }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(collection.find({category:{$exists:true}})){}
if(collection.find({"category.subcategory":{$exists:true}})){}
```

[Exists](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mongodb-check-the-existence-of-the-fields-in-the-specified-collection/)